# MSYS2 : GCC with OpenMP library working but clang with OpenMP not working

Tags: clang, msys2

I am getting below error while compiling code with clang compiler in MSYS2 terminal.

Same it working for GCC with OpenMP in MSYS2 environment.

> > gcc main.c -o main -fopenmp  ---> working
> >
> > clang main.c -o main -fopenmp ---> Not working I am getting below errors

Could anyone let me know what went wrong here?

$ clang main.c -o main -fopenmp
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to`omp_set_dynamic'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to`omp_set_num_threads'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `__kmpc_fork_call'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to`__kmpc_for_static_init_4'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:\msys64\tmp\main-f23226.o:main.c:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to`__kmpc_for_static_fini'

Comment: The code I was executed

int main() {
    printf("Threads: %d\n", omp_get_max_threads());
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        printf("I am thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}

Comment: Can you try it with GCC and CLang from http://winlibs.com/ ?